# splitting files in C- Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, include

I'm new to the subject of splitting files and header files in C.
 I get a `Segmentation fault` (core dumped) when i'm trying to run main. I don't get any more errors.
I tried to trace the problam and I think it is the line:

`syntax_check(fp, symb_table, &IC, &DC);` in the main.c.

I'm just trying to pass from `main.c` the parameters `*fp` and another `array strcture(symbol[])` to a function in `syntax_check(in syntax_check.c)` and do some actions.

main.c:

```
#include "main.h"
int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  int DC=0;
  int IC=100;
  symbol symb_table[20]; 
  if (!(fp=fopen("file.txt", "r")))
  {
   printf("Error opening file");
   exit(0);
  } 
  syntax_check(fp, symb_table, &IC, &DC);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0; 
}
```

main.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
char name[10];
int address;
int external; 
int action;
} symbol;

int syntax_check(FILE*, symbol[], int*, int*);
```

syntax_check.c:

```
#include "syntax_check.h" 

int syntax_check(FILE *fp, symbol symb_table[], int *IC, int *DC)
{
  char buff[80];        /*line to read*/
  char buff2[20];       /**/
  int i=0;
  fgets (buff, 80, fp);
  while (buff[i]!='\0'||buff[i]!=' '||buff[i]!='\t')
  {
    buff2[i]=buff[i];
    i++;
  }
  buff[i]='\0';
  if (exist(buff2))
    printf("legal");
  else
    printf("illegal");
  return 0;
}
```

syntax_check.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  char name[10];
  int address;
  int external;
  int action; 
} symbol;


FILE *fp;

int exist(char action[]);
```

Comment: `(a != b) || (a != c)` - if b and c are not equal, what is the truth value if this expression?

Comment: `buff2[i]=buff[i];` might overflow `buff2`, if there is a word longer than 19 symbols. It also does not 0-terminate `buff2`.

Comment: First, thanks for the help. do you mean to the while loop in syntax_check.c? I need to check it for later.... but the problam is that I stuck in main.c and i get segmentation-fault when I call syntax_check

Comment: What is `exist`?

Comment: a function in another file

Comment: @joe you should show that function. The problem might be _there_

Comment: Probably not the direct cause of your problem, but the `typedef` for `symbol` appears in `main.h` and in `syntax_check.h`. This is highly fishy. It should appear only in `syntax_check.h` and you should include `syntax_check.h` in `main.c`. And you should remove `FILE *fp;` from `syntax_check.h`, it has no purpose.

Comment: O.K. Again,  i'm new to this but I really think the problam is with the call of syntax_check. I will edit.- Michael Walz

Comment: You should also show a minimal example of `file.txt`. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: Your logic in this expression is wrong: `buff[i] != '\0' || buff[i] != ' ' || buff[i] != '\t'`. Have a closer look at it and think about what could be wrong

Comment: Why don't you change "thinking" to "knowing" where the problem is? Run the code in a debugger and it'll tell you exactly what line it's crashing on.